# What is PCT for a materialized view?

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

Saw it in a reference manual. What is PCT for a materialized view?

What is "Partition Change Tracking"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Oracle documentation itself](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14223/advmv.htm#sthref575) :

> "It is possible and advantageous to track freshness to a finer grain
>   than the entire materialized view. The ability to identify which rows
>   in a materialized view are affected by a certain detail table
>   partition, is known as Partition Change Tracking. When one or more of
>   the detail tables are partitioned, it may be possible to identify the
>   specific rows in the materialized view that correspond to a modified
>   detail partition(s); those rows become stale when a partition is
>   modified while all other rows remain fresh."